# Joint density and expected value of iid uniform

Tags: statistics

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d uniform on the interval $(0,\theta)$, so $f(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}$. What is the joint density function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ ?

So  I figured that the joint density function is $n!\prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i)=\frac{n!}{\theta^n}$, since they're independent you multiply the $f(X_i)$'s and then the $n!$ is for the orderings. Is my reasoning and answer correct?

Comment: Integrate your expression over the range of all possible values of the $X_i$. Does it integrate to 1?

Comment: @JohnBarber It integrates to $\frac{n!}{\theta^{n-1}}$, the only function that integrates to $1$ over that range is $f(x)$, but $f(x)$ isn't the join density right?

Comment: Don't just integrate your expression over one of the $X_i$ to check it. Integrate it over all of the $X_i$. You'll find it integrates to $n!$, not 1, and thus cannot be correct. If $X_1,...,X_n$ are truly independent, then their joint distribution is simply the product of their respective individual distributions. No need for the $n!$ factor.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, thank you!